# SPLIT_STRING to get first or second part

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2019

I am stuck searching for a way to do the following. I have a simple table which looks

```
+-------------------+----------+----------+
| coord             | lat      | lng      |
+-------------------+----------+----------+
| 9.08273, 10.92773 |          |          |
+-------------------+----------+----------+
```

What I want is

```
+-------------------+----------+----------+
| coord             | lat      | lng      |
+-------------------+----------+----------+
| 9.08273, 10.92773 |  9.08273 | 10.92773  |
+-------------------+----------+----------+
```

I looked at [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and also at [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x) @SO, but there does not seem to exist something like

```
STRING_SPLIT(columnname, ', ')[1]
STRING_SPLIT(columnname, ', ')[2]
```

to use this later maybe in a way like

```
UPDATE tablename SET lat = STRING_SPLIT(columnname, ', ')[1], SET lng = STRING_SPLIT(columnname, ', ')[2];
```

All approaches end up in creating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STRING_SPLIT` is a table-valued function so returns a record for each string it splits out.  You don't want multiple records.  You simply want to split a single string so use `CHARINDEX` to find the position of the comma, the `LEFT` and `SUBSTRING` to carve up the string based on that position.  Here's and an example of a similar technique using a Common Table Expression (CTE), being as you're new n all:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.yourTable
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.yourTable ( 
    coord   VARCHAR(30), 
    lat     DECIMAL(10,5),
    lng     DECIMAL(10,5)
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.yourTable ( coord )
VALUES ( '9.08273, 10.92773' )
GO

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *, CHARINDEX( ',', coord ) commaPos
FROM dbo.yourTable
)
UPDATE cte
SET lat = LEFT( coord, commaPos - 1 ), 
    lng = SUBSTRING( coord, commaPos + 1, 20 )

SELECT *
FROM dbo.yourTable
```

My results:

[image: My results]

See the way I've created a test table and some sample data, and made the script re-runnable, you could do that for future questions, and who people what you've tried and what errors you get.  This approach will generally get you a better response and attract less downvotes.  I have upvoted your question, but it looks like you're already behind.

Have a look through [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) too, particularly if you've found the post helpful.

Comment: Please don't use images for code, data or errors. Use formatted text.